# Set and Read a multidimensional array

Tags: java

So... i'm seeing Java for Web just today and i've already have a huge project at work. I'm used to PHP and C++ so i'm not having so many troubles learning this language but i've stuck in that question.

I have a void that have a multidimensional array in that format:

```
array( "data" => array ( "Name" => "John", "Age" => "16" ) )
```

my question is:

**How can i set my method to accept that kind of array (above) and how can i read that multidimensional array (bellow)?**

e.g.:

```
public void getArray(String[] data) { println(data["data"]["Name"]; }
```

-

```
getArray(array("data" => array("Name" => "John", "Age" => "16")));

// to returns: 'John'
```

--

Obs.: Sorry if this is a dumb question, i really don't have any knowledge in Java. I'm going to study but for know i really need that question answered.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's arrays aren't actually arrays, they're [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). Java's version is [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

```
HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
data.put("Name", "John");
// etc.
System.out.println(data.get("Name"));
```

You should also look into classes, since that's how non-PHP programmers generally do this sort of thing:

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
         return this.name;
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Then:

```
class SomeClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person("John", 16);
        HashMap<String, Person> people = new HashMap<String, Person>();
        people.put(person.getName(), person);
    }
}
```

Classes can make things substantially simpler for large projects, since they can do more than just hold values:

```
class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a person's full name (first and last name), without
     * storing it as a seperate variable internally.
     */
    public String getName() {
         return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
         return this.firstName;
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Plus, you get type safety. It's much nicer to find out about problems at compile time, since you can solve them before you deploy the application, instead of after.

Answer (score 0):

What i do when i use a multidimensional array is somthing like this:

```
public class SayHello 
{

public String[][] test;

public void Main(String[] args)
{
  SayHello test = new SayHello();
  test.test = new String[4][4];
  test.testMethod(test.test);
}

private void testMethod(String[][] array)
{
for(int i = 0; i<array.length;i++) {
  for(int x = 0;x<array[i].length;x++) {
     System.out.println(array[i][x]);
  }
}
  System.out.println(array[0][1]);
}
}
```

I hop this helps you out a bit